# g.drawImage not successful, completely stumped

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, drawimage

Trying to draw an image and I have no idea why it's not appearing on the screen. Image is loaded fine.

System.out.printf("%nPlayer_1.img_player1 is: "+Player_1.img_player1); says that the image is loaded correctly (correct image w/h etc).

Have tried all manner of image observers, drawing the image from different classes (namely Player_1.drawSquare and MyPanel.painComponent)

There are regular repaint() requests coming in from the Control class, but I do not believe this is preventing the drawing.

No error's are thrown.

player_1.gif is located within the game_2 package, I have tried running the code with it in the src and root folder.

```
package test;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.net.URL;
public class Main{
 public static void main(String[] args) {
     GUI.main(args);
 }
}

class GUI {
static JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            createAndShowGUI(); 
        }
    });
}

private static void createAndShowGUI() {
    System.out.printf("%nCreated GUI on EDT? "+
    SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());

    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
    f.add(new MyPanel());
    f.setSize(640,640);
    f.setVisible(true);


} 

}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

public MyPanel() {

    //setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
}


public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
    return new Dimension(640,640);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);       
    System.out.printf("%nPaincomponent on GUI");

    Player_1.paintSquare(g);
    System.out.printf("%nPlayer_1.img_player1 is: "+Player_1.img_player1);

}

}

class Player_1{
public static Image img_player1;
public int int_x = 0;
public int int_y = 1;
public int int_w = 1;
public int int_h = 1;

public static void paintSquare(Graphics g){
     if (img_player1 == null)
         img_player1 = IOControl.getImage("player_1.gif");

    g.drawImage(img_player1, 32, 32, 32, 32, GUI.f);

}
}
class IOControl {

public static void main(String[] args) {

}

static BufferedImage getImage(String path)
{

    BufferedImage tempImage = null;
        try
        {

                URL imageURL = Main.class.getResource(path);
                tempImage = toBufferedImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(imageURL));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
                System.out.printf("%nAn error occured -" + e.getMessage());
        }
        System.out.printf("%n"+path);
        System.out.printf("%nIOControl.path");

        System.out.printf("%n"+tempImage);
        System.out.printf("%nIOControl.tempImage");
        return tempImage;


}

public static BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img)
{
    if (img instanceof BufferedImage)
    {
        return (BufferedImage) img;
    }

    // Create a buffered image with transparency
    BufferedImage bimage = new BufferedImage(32, 32, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Draw the image on to the buffered image
    Graphics2D bGr = bimage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();

    // Return the buffered image
    return bimage;
}
}
```

Comment: **1)** Choose better Class names and variables that use Java naming convention. Variables an class names use camel casing. Also you've named a variable `Player_1` with the type `Player_1`. Not sure if it's confusing to you, but it sure is to me. **2)** Don't unnecessarily use `static` and you are way over doing. **3)** Don't create your image in the method that will be painting `paintSquare`. **4)** Show your `IOControl.getImage` method and mention where `"player_1.gif"` is located in your file structure.

Comment: **5)** Consider posting a compilable example we can test out. In it's current state, it is not compilable due to missing classes. Take out the code that is unnecessary and include the classes that _are_ necessary. Make sure it compiles, then edit your post with the example.

Comment: Still doesn't compile. Do this, create Just one .java file, whatever class is your main launching class. Put _all_ your classes into that file. Leave out the `public` in the class names that except for the main class. If you can can create one file that will compile, then we should be able to test it out also.

Comment: I have updated the post with player_1.gif location and the IOControl.getImage method. I am currently making a compilable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Don't call the `main` method. It is meant for the JVM to call as the starting point of your program. Also, you should only have *one* `main` method, in whichever class is the launching class.
2. Don't create the image in the `paintXxx` method. You should create in the constructor.
3. All the other faulty points I mentioned in my comments in the original post.
4. It looks like your main problem is in the `getImage` method. I simplified it for you and it works (given I fixed the other points I mentioned above).

   ```
   public static BufferedImage getImage(String path) {
       BufferedImage img = null;
       try {
           img = ImageIO.read(GUI.class.getResource(path));
       } catch (IOException ex) {
           ex.printStackTrace();
       }
       return img;
   }
   ```

Here's the full running code. Note: you had the image location correct, with it in the same package as the `Main` class.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new GUI().createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}

class GUI {

    JFrame f = new JFrame("Swing Paint Demo");

    public void createAndShowGUI() {
        System.out.printf("%nCreated GUI on EDT? "
                + SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());

        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(new MyPanel());
        f.setSize(640, 640);
        f.setVisible(true);

    }

}

class MyPanel extends JPanel {

    Player_1 player1;

    public MyPanel() {
        player1 = new Player_1(MyPanel.this);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(640, 640);
    }

    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        System.out.printf("%nPaincomponent on GUI");

        player1.paintSquare(g);

    }

}

class Player_1 {

    public Image img_player1;
    public int int_x = 0;
    public int int_y = 1;
    public int int_w = 1;
    public int int_h = 1;
    JPanel panel;

    public Player_1(JPanel panel) {
        this.panel = panel;
        img_player1 = IOControl.getImage("player_1.png");
    }

    public void paintSquare(Graphics g) {
        g.drawImage(img_player1, 32, 32, 32, 32, panel);
    }
}

class IOControl {

    public static BufferedImage getImage(String path) {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(GUI.class.getResource(path));
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```